# how to send minicom to background?

Tags: bash, serial-port, background-process

I need to log some data from a serial device. So I would like to first call minicom with the `&` parameter:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyXYZ -b 115200 -C logFile &
```

But taking a look to `ps aux` shows, that minicom had become a terminated zombie process:

```
edeviser   8835  0.0  0.0  19696  2628 pts/0    T    15:29   0:00 minicom -D /dev/ttyXYZ -b 115200 -C logFile
```

How to send minicom to background?

---

Further information:
I would like to send it to background because I'll need to trigger some actions after minicom has started to log the serial data to the logFile. Using `cat /dev/ttyXYZ > logFile` is no option, because I must specify the baudrate. Using a second terminal is also no option, because this work will be done by a bash script.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
nohup minicom -D /dev/ttyXYZ -b 115200 -C logFile &
```

I ran into the same issue when I was trying to convert movies with handbrake-cli. 
nohup will background the task and push the output into a txt file called `nohup.txt.`